# Is there a way to retrieve one's own edit of a different participant's PSE question, if the edit was rejected within hours of being sent?

Tags: support

I spent a few hours this morning, attempting an edit of a PSE question (similar to many bearing on those aspects of space that are often described as representing its expansion) that I'd attempted to relate to two cosmological models:  Penrose's CCC model and Poplawski's torsion-based model.  Although I'd written the edit down, I've misplaced that paper content and am surprised to find that I can't locate the electronic one either.  (I'd expected the approval of the edit to be fairly routine, as I'd included references that observationally sustained some of the aspects of those models, as well as references to recent work by a Rutgers professor of philosophy which explicitly bore on both of those models:  However, the usual search term algorithms bring up nothing, and neither does the algorithm relating my PSE icon to my "activity" today [MST].)  Is there any way I can see my very recently-edited version of a PSE question that had been put on hold (for reasons that I don't recollect exactly, but basically due to its lack of specificity)?

Comment: Never trust anything to a web interface. Keep master (or backup) copies locally in text files of anything important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just go to "Activity > All actions > Suggestions" on your user profile to see all of your edit suggestions, both approved and rejected.

Assuming your edit in question was [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/346854), your edit pretty clearly just replaces the question wholesale. If you want to ask a new question, just ask a new question.

Comment: I appreciate your finding of my edit (which, as I'd stated, was my main purpose in questioning meta), as I hadn't been aware of the procedure, but, as generic expansion alone does not necessarily include subdivision of any volume being expanded,  I don't believe that my edit should've been rejected.

Comment: @Edouard Your edit wasn't rejected because of the physics content. It was rejected because it's not asking the same thing as the original question, and would invalidate the existing answers on the question.

Comment: Invalidation of the existing answers is what I hadn't recognized.

Comment: @Edouard To be clear, even if there were no existing answers to be invalidated, this big of an edit which completely changes the meaning of the question is not allowed.